# Problem Importing KML QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, qgis-processing, kml, kmz

I'm pretty new at QGis.

Whenever I try to import KML into QGIS, I do not see any of the points I imported. Somedays ago I could. I don't understand what's happening and the reason about this.

[image]

Comment: Is it just an issue with the embedded symbology or is the attribute table empty for those layers?

Comment: The polygons do not have any attributes. But The "KMZ" do have. But can't see them anyways...